# What's the difference between scatter/spread/ or disperse?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, differences, learning

If you want to say people of the same race, the Romany people for instance, have moved to different parts of the world throughout history, how can we say that in fluent English? I have looked up the verbs *scatter* and *spread*, but I can't decide which one sounds more natural since all examples are about news spreading or plants scattering.

> Romany people have **spread** from Eastern Asia to the far end of Europe and America.
>   Romany people have **scattered** from Eastern Asia to the far end of Europe and America.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different connotations to the three words.

> The Romany people are spread across Asia and Europe

suggests that in all parts of Asia and Europe there are Romany people.

> The Romany people are scattered across Asia and Europe

suggests that there are individual groups of Romany people in different parts of Asia and Europe but also by implication there are many areas where there are no Romany people at all. There may be isolated communities in several places.

The word "dispersed" places more emphasis on being sent away from a particular place.

> After the Siege of Jerusalem, the Jews were dispersed around the world.

The point made by "dispersed" is that they were sent away from Jerusalem.

In the case of the Romany people they are to be found all over the place, I think, and if that is what you want to say then "spread" is better than "scattered", but if you want to say they live in many separate and distinct communities then "scattered" may better convey your meaning. If your point is not about where they are now, but rather that in the past they were driven away from their original homelands you might go for "dispersed".